# How to have a custom navigation controller supply the same custom navBar buttons to each storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

What I want is to use custom buttons instead of the back button and title inside the nav bar of a navigation controller. I created a custom navigation controller. Inside the custom nav controller(inside of the viewdidload function), I have this:

```
let leftButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(
     title: "My Connections",
     style: .done,
     target: self,
     action: #selector(goToPartners)
     )

   let middleButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(
     title: "Home",
     style: .done,
     target: self,
     action: #selector(goHome)
     )

self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems([leftButtonItem, middleButtonItem], animated: false)
```

I have no errors, but nothing shows up in my nav bar except for the title(which is automatically inherited from that storyboards title)

Comment: doublecheck you are using the custom class you created

Comment: yes I am, I set the class in the nav controller already

Answer (score 2):

The `setLeftBarButtonItems` will not work in this case. This is because `setLeftBarButtonItems` is used to execute transition to the bar button items.

Just replace it with leftBarButtonItems as given below in `ViewDidLoad` of your View Controller:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [leftButtonItem, middleButtonItem]
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: This did not solve my problem, now getting an error of "cannot call value of non-function type 'UIBarButtonItem' ".

Comment: Are you using swift 3.0, or a lower version?

Answer (score 0):

Overriding `viewDidLoad` of the navigation controller isn't going to help you as it will only execute when the navigation contoller is first loaded. As each view controller is pushed, the button items will be updated.

I suggest that you implement a `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and use that to update the `navigationItem` in the [`navigationController(_:willShow:animated:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontrollerdelegate/1621878-navigationcontroller) method

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, I ended up having to make a custom uiviewcontroller class, and used setleftbarbutton items and setrightbarbutton inside the viewdidload function, then just inheriting the class into all my viewcontrollers.